# How to specify AddIn process names?

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, maf

I am using the Microsoft AddIn Framework to load AddIn assemblies.  I am running them in their own process as to separate them from the service.  The thing I don't like it that every AddIn process shows up as AddInProcess32.exe in the task manager.  When using process isolation, how can we rename the name that shows in the taskmanager so that it's more descriptinve for users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not.

Filename for that process is hardcoded in private method *GetProcessName(Platform platform)* which is called in constructor of the **System.AddIn.Hosting.AddInProcess** class.
And System.AddIn.Hosting.AddInProcess is a sealed class so it can't be inherited and that method can't be overriden.

The only way to customize process name for your add-in is to decline idea about using System.AddIn framework and create your own.

Here is a good list of articles about creating plugin architecture in c# with a lot of examples: [Creating a plug-in framework in C#: Resources](http://blog.caljacobson.com/2007/07/26/creating-a-plug-in-framework-in-c-resources/).