# Give MAF  plugin which run as separate process a custom name

Tags: .net, plugins, maf

I activate my plugin using MAF[Managed Add - In Framework] in a separate process.

> The problem is that it gives default name "AddInProcess32" to the each
>   plugin which run as a separate process.

**Can i give a custom name to the process which MAF create? If so how ?**

*PS: Why i want to give custom name? Because i do not want user to kill process by mistake...
I want to give process a name which shows it is part of my app clearly.*

Comment: +1 (and then some ...) to offset your generous bounty a tiny bit at least ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While desirable indeed, this is unfortunately not possible, as analyzed correctly by Dos095-russ already in his answer to the identical question [How to specify AddIn process names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353093/45773) (+1 over there).

To make the bounty worth your while a bit at least, I'll add some context though:

The *Filename for that process is hardcoded* in the constructor of the [AddInProcess Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinprocess.aspx) due to the very purpose the class has been designed for, namely to *Provide[s] an external process for running add-ins out-of-process from the host application*. The specific mechanics are touched in the *Remarks* section:

> The executable that runs the add-in is obtained from one of two files
>   installed with the .NET Framework under the Windows directory. By
>   default, the executable that matches the bits-per-word of the host
>   application is used. If the host is a 64-bit process, AddInProcess.exe
>   is run; otherwise, AddInProcess32.exe is run. To specify the way the
>   executable is selected, use the AddInProcess(Platform) constructor to
>   create the AddInProcess object.

The main reasons for why out-of-process add-ins might be needed *by some* applications are properly summarized in Danielg's answer to [Choosing between MEF and MAF (System.AddIn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin). If those do actually not apply to your use case, you could explore the answers and links provided for [Is MEF a replacement for System.Addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840441/45773) in order to judge, whether the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) might be a better solution in fact - it's excellent for what it does btw., very easy to program with and widely used accordingly.

Comment: Well, MEF does not give me isolation. I have to start my plugin as a separate process...